# How to develop a mock service for a RESTful webservice call using spock

Tags: java, junit, spock

I am trying to develop a mock service for the RESTful API client (`PricingClaimRestServiceClient`). In the below `JUnit` class if you see, the RESTful API client is called after some nested method calls. Actually I don't want to mock everything (all nested stuff), I want only when this RESTful API is called then it should call the mock service instead of original RESTful API client (`PricingClaimRestServiceClient`). Please suggest how my `JUnit` and Spock code should be.

Secondly, I need to write the Spock code in a `.groovy` file and existing `JUnit` code is in `.java` file. So I need to use the `groovyshell` or `groovyclassloader` to call the Spock code `.groovy` file from the `JUnit` code. Correct?

FYI, Nested method call:

```java
Assert.assertTrue(bundleReportService.priceBundle(bundle));
  /* -> */ bundleReport = providerPricingIntegrationService.getPricingClaimDetails(bundle);
  /* -> */ pricingClaimRestServiceClient.getPricingClaimResponse(pricingRequestXml);
```

**My `JUnit` test class:**

```java
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(loader = ConfigurationAwareContextLoader.class, locations = {"/integrationTest-ApplicationContext.xml"})
public class BundleReportServiceIT extends BatchTestCase {

@Autowired
protected BundleReportService bundleReportService;

Bundle bundle;
@Before
  public void setUp() throws Exception {
    Get the bundle setup
  }

@Test
  public void testPriceBundle() {
    bundle.getTriggerClaimLines().get(0).setValueCache(getValueCache());

    Assert.assertTrue(bundleReportService.priceBundle(bundle));
  }
}
```

`BundleReportServiceImpl` class:

```java
public class BundleReportServiceImpl extends BasicService implements BundleReportService {

  public Boolean priceBundle(Bundle bundle) {
    BundleReport bundleReport;
    try {
      bundleReport = providerPricingIntegrationService.getPricingClaimDetails(bundle);
    } catch (Throwable t) {
      logger.error(String.format("Error in pricing integration service:%s", t));
      throw t;
    }

}
```

`ProviderPricingIntegrationServiceImpl` class:

```java
public class ProviderPricingIntegrationServiceImpl implements ProviderPricingIntegrationService {

  @Override
  @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.NOT_SUPPORTED)
  public BundleReport getPricingClaimDetails(Bundle bundle) throws BundlePricingException {

// call rest client to hit service.
      clientResponse = pricingClaimRestServiceClient.getPricingClaimResponse(pricingRequestXml);  

    }
}
```

RESTful API client to call other applications for which I want to create a mock service.

```java
public class PricingClaimRestServiceClient {

  @PostConstruct
  void initWebResource() {
    ApacheHttpClient client = ApacheHttpClient.create();
    client.addFilter(new HTTPBasicAuthFilter(userName, password));
    client.setReadTimeout(requestTimeout);
    ppRequestBuilder = client.resource(rootUri.trim()).path(SECURED_API_APPENDER);
  }

  /**
   * create resource to call pricing claim service with apache http client.
   */
  private WebResource getResource() {
    return ppRequestBuilder;
  }

  public String getPricingClaimResponse(String pricingRequestXml) {
    ClientResponse clientResponse = getResource().path(PRICING_API + PRICING_API_END_POINT)
        .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
        .accept(REQUEST_ACCEPT_TYPE_V14)
        .post(ClientResponse.class, pricingRequestXml);

    String response = clientResponse.getEntity(String.class);

    if (clientResponse.getStatus() != 200) {
      throw new RuntimeException("Error while calling pricing claim service. Service status code is  : " + clientResponse.getStatus());
    }
    return response;
  }
}
}
```

Comment: Your build needs to compile your Groovy code (into .class files). Your JUnit tests will import and use those classes.  Compiled Groovy classes are executed by the JVM so as long as they are on the classpath they can be used by the unit tests.

Comment: You write your test either in JUnit or in Spock, not call one from the other. Spock uses a JUnit runner, so JUnit or Maven plugins such as Surefire and Failsafe will run Spock tests automatically when configured correctly. It is also possible to use both JUnit tests (written in Java or Groovy) and Spock tests (written in Groovy) together in one project if you think that makes sense. Other than what I have said, your question is too unclear for me to answer.

Comment: Thank you Paul and Kriegaex.In regards to my first question, please suggest.
I want to develop a mock service for REST API client (PricingClaimRestServiceClient). In my Junit, after some nested method calls finally it's calling the original REST API call. So I don't want to mock all the nested stuff. I just want to develop a mock REST API client , when finally called it will invoke the Mock REST client instead of the original. Please suggest how my junit/spock code will be?